# Highcharts Label Formatter Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using the formatter to add a line break for each space in my x-axis labels in a highchart column chart. But when you scroll all the way to the right, it has a glitch/issue.

**Issue:** Scroll all the way to the right causes flickering and once I get all the way to the right on my page, I get "this.value.replace is not a function" error. But only when I get all the way to the right.

**Demo:** [Here is it](http://jsfiddle.net/0a499j2L/2/)

**Goal:** Smooth scroll while having breaks for each space in label.

**Code:**

```
  $(function () {

      $('#container10').highcharts({
          // colors: [Complete],
          chart: {
              type: 'column'
          },
          title: {
              text: ''
          },
          xAxis: {
              categories: [
                  'SKIN CARE FACIAL',
                  'SKIN HAND AND BODY LOTION',
                  'HAIR SHAMPOO / CONDITIONER / FIXATIVES',
                  'COUGH COLD SUNCARE (RACK 1)',
                  ' SKIN CARE FACIAL (COS Stores)',
                  ' RK 1 COUGH COLD SUNCARE (RACK 1)',
                  ' SKIN BAR SOAP / LIQUID SOAP',
                  ' COUGH COLD ALLERGY (RACK 2)',
                  'SUNCARE IN-LINE',
                  'RK 2 COUGH COLD ALLERGY (RACK 2)',
                  'ORAL CARE (COS Stores)',
                  'WOMENS BODY WASH (COS Stores)',
                  'DIGESTIVE (COS Stores)',
                  'HAIR SHAMPOO / CONDITIONER / FIXATIVES_MACRO',
                  'MENS SHAVE (COS Stores)',
                  'COSMETICS',

              ],
              min: 0,
              max: 5,
              labels: {
                  step: 1,
                  formatter: function () {
                      return this.value.replace(/ /g, '<br />');
                  },
                  style: {
                      fontSize: 9
                  }
              }
          },
          yAxis: {

              title: {
                  text: ''
              }
          },
          legend: {
              enabled: false
          },
          tooltip: {
              formatter: function () {
                  var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';

                  $.each(this.points.reverse(), function () {
                      s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': $' + this.y.toFixed(0);
                  });

                  return s;
              },
              shared: true
          },
          plotOptions: {
              column: {
                  stacking: 'normal',
                  dataLabels: {
                      enabled: true,
                      //  color: TextColor,
                      style: {
                          // textShadow: '0 0 3px black',
                          fontSize: 10
                      }
                  }
              }
          },

          scrollbar: {
              enabled: true,
              barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
              barBorderRadius: 7,
              barBorderWidth: 0,
              buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
              buttonBorderWidth: 0,
              buttonBorderRadius: 7,
              trackBackgroundColor: 'none',
              trackBorderWidth: 1,
              trackBorderRadius: 8,
              trackBorderColor: '#CCC',
              rifleColor: 'black',
              buttonArrowColor: 'black',
          },

          series: [{

              name: 'Spent',
              data: [
              39362.06,
              33778.00,
              9246.24,
              4266.45,
              3469.14,
              2982.95,
              2898.72,
              1778.25,
              1659.64,
              1479.00,
              902.15,
              702.37,
              281.54,
              111.32,
              93.89,
              45.53,

              ],
              legendIndex: 0

          }]
      });
  });
```

Comment: I realize this doesn't answer your question, but I can't help but point out how much easier this would be to display as a horizontal bar chart, and do away with your problem in the first place:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/51/

Comment: That does not make it easier, I'm making a dashboard with 6 charts on one screen. It has to scroll.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify: it's easier for the user, who can actually read and make sense of a bar chart, as opposed to a big jumbled scrolling column chart with giant broken axis labels...  To put it bluntly. The point of a dashboard is to be able to view everything at once. If you have to scroll individual charts, it entirely defeats the purpose, and they may as well be on separate pages.  6 charts is not a lot to fit on one dahsboard - shouldn't be a big challenge to do it without destroying the effectiveness of each chart. FWIW

Comment: You must do what you must do, of course. But my point stands, for anyone interested in making a dashboard that is actually useful. :)

Comment: I'd be happy to help with methods to effectively display 200 categories on chart on a dashboard, but we've clearly gone beyond the scope of the question here.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your formatter, use html labels and set whiteSpace to normal:

```
labels: {
    step: 1,
    useHTML:true,
    style: {
        fontSize: '9px',
        whiteSpace: 'normal'
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0a499j2L/3/

Comment: It's runs smooth for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Weird. Chrome. My other charts with the scroll are working fine.

Comment: With the change it runs smoothy in Chrome for me.  Without, I see the glitch.  Btw, fontSize should be '9px' instead of 9.

Comment: Thanks. I'll mess with it and see.